# Joining two datasets with different number of observations

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

I have two datasets that contain the population and the longitude/latitude of subregions. Since there are several geographical entries per subregion, I want to join these datasets in a way that the population is displayed in every single corresponding geographical row. I have tried every dplyr command (inner_join, full_join etc) but can't make it work. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Dataset 1 (100 observations)

```
subregion    population 

adams        66949
alexander     7051
bond         17137
...          ...
```

Dataset 2 (10000 observations)

```
subregion   longitude   latitude

adams       -91.49563    40.21018
adams       -90.91121    40.19299
adams       -90.91694    39.75754
alexander   -89.20380    37.32247
...         ...          ...
```

Desired dataset

```
subregion   longitude   latitude   population

adams       -91.49563    40.21018  66949
adams       -90.91121    40.19299  66949
adams       -90.91694    39.75754  66949
alexander   -89.20380    37.32247   7051
...         ...          ...
```

Comment: So `bond` of df1 shouldn't be in the final result since it's not in df2?

Comment: Did you try `dplyr::left_join(Dataset2, Dataset1, by= 'subregion')` ?

Comment: `left_join(dateset1, dateset2,by="subregion"` should work

Comment: Sadly, the left_join command does not work in merging my datasets. But since it has been recommend twice, I guess there is another problem with my current dataset.

Comment: @MalteS. In that case, you need to check whether `subregion` column is same in both dataset ie: capital case, whitespace

Comment: You can do `str(dataset)` and maybe see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

```
#library(tibble) # uncomment if needed to access tribble()

B <- tribble(  # Using tribble to make quick, easy df's from your post
  ~subregion,    ~population ,
  "adams",        66949,
  "alexander",     7051,
  "bond",         17137)

A <- tribble(
  ~subregion,   ~longitude,   ~latitude,
  "adams",       -91.49563,    40.21018,
  "adams",       -90.91121,    40.19299,
  "adams",       -90.91694,    39.75754,
  "alexander",   -89.20380,    37.32247)

merge(A,B,by="subregion")

#> merge(A,B,by="subregion")
#  subregion longitude latitude population

#1     adams -91.49563 40.21018      66949
#2     adams -90.91121 40.19299      66949
#3     adams -90.91694 39.75754      66949
#4 alexander -89.20380 37.32247       7051
```

NOTE: Bond is dropped. Use

```
merge(A,B,by="subregion",all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
```

if bond's pop is required but lat/long not (vals will be set to NA).

One may keep all from the first frame or the second frame or both (padding with NAs) with the various combos of all.x/all.y set to TRUE or FALSE.